# Run 2 Commands, append to file & show command output on console, but of only one command

Tags: io-redirection, tee

I am attempting to run a Linux command such as nmap & pass the input into the txt2html command which then appends to a file but also show the output of the nmap command only. The command provided works, but it outputs the txt2html output and I just want the nmap output to show on the terminal. Is there a way to do this?

```
nmap localhost | txt2html -extract -8 | tee -a file_to_append
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
nmap localhost | tee /dev/stderr | txt2html -extract -8 >> file_to_append
```

Explanation:

1. You run nmap
2. The output of nmap is sent both file /dev/stderr (which is just standard error) and also stdout
3. txt2html reads the previous steps stdout and appends its output to file_to_append
   Now stderror was never redirected so it would should appear in your console for you to see.

Here is an example without output with some dummy commands

```
$ echo hi | tee /dev/stderr | sed "s/hi/bye/" > /tmp/test.txt
hi
$ cat /tmp/test.txt
bye
```

You can see the terminal output and the saved contents differ

Comment: Ahh worked like a charm, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using a shell that supports process substitutions with `>(...)`, then you could use `tee` to redirect into the `txt2html` command for you:

```bash
nmap localhost | tee >(txt2html -extract -8 >>some-file)
```

Here, `txt2html` gets its input from `tee` and appends its output to `some-file`.

Apart from writing to `txt2html`, `tee` would also write its original input to the standard output stream, which presumably would be connected to the terminal.

In this scenario, any diagnostic output from `nmap` would bypass both `tee` and `txt2html` and be sent directly to the terminal.  If you instead want to process this, redirect the output of the command on the left-hand side of the pipeline with `2>&1` so that its standard error stream is redirected along with the standard output stream.